# SharePoint PickerTreeView throwing null exception

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, feature-activation, features

When clicking the browse button for selection of document library or site null exception error occurs.

This is the url of the popup that opens:
  _layouts/15/PickerTreeView.aspx?title=CbqPickerSelectListTitle&text=CbqPickerSelectListText&filter=websListsFolders&root=&selection=&featureId=&errorString=&iconUrl=/_layouts/15/images/smt_icon.gif?rev=23&scopeToWeb=true&requireCT=&sourceId=

Here is the stack trace:
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.WebControls.ObjectSerializer.evaluateTestAutomationId(CachedList cachedListToEval)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.WebControls.ObjectSerializer.get_AutomationId()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.WebControls.EcbEnabledTreeNode.RenderPreText(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNode.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer, Int32 position, Boolean[] isLast, Boolean enabled)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNode.RenderChildNodes(HtmlTextWriter writer, Int32 depth, Boolean[] isLast, Boolean enabled)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNode.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer, Int32 position, Boolean[] isLast, Boolean enabled)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeView.RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at ASP._layouts_15_dialog_master.__RenderPlaceHolderDialogBodySection(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer) in c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\dialog.master:line 209
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at ASP._layouts_15_dialog_master.__RenderDialogForm(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer) in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\cf1d427e\d66940a6\App_Web_dialog.master.9c9699a8.4miwtrwi.0.cs:line 0
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
   at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at ASP._layouts_15_dialog_master.__Render__control1(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer) in c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\dialog.master:line 8
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.UnsecuredLayoutsPageBase.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.DeltaPage.RenderToBase(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.DeltaPage.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.UnsecuredLayoutsPageBase.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

I have tried enabling disabling Publishing feature. This is happening on my site collection. Including all the subsites. Please help

Comment: did you ever find the solution?